# T-SQL to stamp individual rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor

I'm looking for some T-SQL code that will add a column called tag which will tag each row with the same number until there is a change in value within any of the columns "team", "id", "kmvid", "name", "cid" and "pid". If there is a change, use the next sequence of numbering for that row. See the expected results below as image.

[image]

Comment: you should include your attempt and also mention the version of your database.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't include `cid` or `pid` columns. There is no order specified for the rows. You haven't tagged the question with the database, e.g. `sql-server`. (`tsql` narrows the choices, but it isn't specific.) No signs of attempts or research on your part. And you didn't include a question. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your "question".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with cumulative sums and `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_team = team and
                     id = id and
                     kmvid = kmvid and
                     name = name and
                     prev_id = id and
                     prev_cid = pid and
                     prev_oid = cid
                 then 1 else 0
            end) over (order by date) as Tag
from (select t.*,
             lag(team) over (order by date) as prev_team,
             lag(id) over (order by date) as prev_id,
             lag(kmvid) over (order by date) as prev_kmvid,
             lag(name) over (order by date) as prev_name,
             lag(cid) over (order by date) as prev_cid,
             lag(pid) over (order by date) as prev_pid
      from t
     ) t;
```

You should not use a cursor for things that are better done using set-based operations.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the desired results based on the data you took a picture of...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    CountryId CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL
    );
INSERT #TestData (CountryId, Date)
SELECT '99', '2004-04-30' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2004-07-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2004-10-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2005-01-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2005-04-30' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2005-07-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2005-10-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '99', '2006-01-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2006-04-30' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2006-07-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2006-10-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT '99', '2007-01-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'HK', '2007-04-30' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'CA', '2007-07-31' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'HK', '2007-10-31';

--  SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--=======================================

WITH 
    cte_TagGroup AS (
        SELECT 
            td.CountryId, 
            td.[Date],
            TagGroup = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY td.Date)
                - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.CountryId ORDER BY td.Date)
                - CASE WHEN td.CountryId = LAG(td.CountryId, 1, td.CountryId) OVER (ORDER BY td.CountryId, td.Date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        FROM
            #TestData td
        )
SELECT 
    tg.CountryId, 
    tg.Date, 
    Tag = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tg.TagGroup)
FROM
    cte_TagGroup tg;
```

... That said, I suspect that the 1st 3 columns of data aren't all the same values, so you may need to add columns to the "PARTITION BY" clauses to make it fit your actual data.

HTH,

Jason